# PHP DomDocument Return Doctype

Tags: php

I thought this was going to be easier than it has been or I am over thinking this.

I am trying to return what the declared doctype is for a html page from a url.
If it is anything other than !DOCTYPE html append it to be !DOCTYPE html.

I have tried several different things...latest being the array return below, but regardless of the page tested the array returned is exactly the same even if the fully declared DOCTYPE is not the same .

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong or how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 


$url="http://www.example.com";

$html = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(htmlentities($html));

$doctype = $doc->doctype;
var_dump($doctype);
```

var_dump returns

```
object(DOMDocumentType)#2 (22) { 
["name"]=> string(4) "html" 
["entities"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" 
["notations"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" 
["publicId"]=> string(37) "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" 
["systemId"]=> string(41) "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd" 
["internalSubset"]=> NULL 
["nodeName"]=> string(4) "html" 
["nodeValue"]=> NULL 
["nodeType"]=> int(10) 
["parentNode"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" 
["childNodes"]=> NULL 
["firstChild"]=> NULL 
["lastChild"]=> NULL 
["previousSibling"]=> NULL 
["nextSibling"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" 
["attributes"]=> NULL 
["ownerDocument"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" 
["namespaceURI"]=> NULL 
["prefix"]=> string(0) "" 
["localName"]=> NULL 
["baseURI"]=> NULL
["textContent"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call **htmlentities**:

    `$html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html></html>';
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML( $html );
    $doctype = $doc->doctype;
    var_dump( $doctype );`

Comment: Thanks you....looking back through the 10 other things I tried....I had your exact code except for var_dump...I was trying to echo it.